# Make React only return after value is not null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I want React to return with a code only after a value was given to a variable.

This piece of code starts my ChatRoom:

```
 <section>
  {user ? <ChatRoom/> : <SignIn />}
 </section>
```

Inside my function I have this code. I am trying to get information from Firestore.

```
firestore.collection("mailpairing").doc(auth.currentUser.email).get().then((d) => {
      
  othermail=d.data().mail;
  console.log("test123",auth.currentUser.email," + ",othermail);

  firestore.collection("tokens").doc(othermail).get().then((da)=> {
  
    othertoken=da.data().token;
    console.log("másik token: " + othertoken);


    
  });
});
```

At the end I have this return statement:

```
if(othertoken!=null){

  console.log("token???");
  return(
    
    <>
    
     <BrowserRouter>
       <Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="tv/indexTv.html?m="+auth.currentUser.email+"&p="+othermail+"&t="+othertoken}} />
      </BrowserRouter>

    </>
  
)}
else{
  return null;
}
```

If I leave the code like this, nothing gets returned. If I remove the if statements, the site gets returned I want, but the token I want to pass into the URL is undefined.
How can I fix this? I can't make the function async for some reason, asking for data from another function did not work.

**Edit:** Solved! I added a UseState.

```
const [HaveToken, setTokenValue] = useState(false);
```

I change it to true after I get the data from Firestore, and I added stuff to the return:

```
{HaveToken ? (
     <BrowserRouter>
       <Route exact path="/" render={() => {window.location.href="tv/intv.html?m="+auth.currentUser.email+"&p="+othermail+"&t="+othertoken}} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    ):null}
```

Now it works well.

Comment: You can make that async with promise

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to get your token in this way, you just need to replace `return` with `resolve function` and you will be good to go.

```
const othertoken = await Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  firestore
    .collection('mailpairing')
    .doc(auth.currentUser.email)
    .get()
    .then(d => {
      othermail = d.data().mail;
      console.log('test123', auth.currentUser.email, ' + ', othermail);

      firestore
        .collection('tokens')
        .doc(othermail)
        .get()
        .then(da => {
          othertoken = da.data().token;
          console.log(`másik token: ${othertoken}`);
          resolve(othertoken);
        });
    });
});
```

In a better way

```
const othertoken = await Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  const d = await firestore.collection('mailpairing').doc(auth.currentUser.email).get();
  const othermail = d.data().mail;
  console.log('test123', auth.currentUser.email, ' + ', othermail);

  const da = await firestore.collection('tokens').doc(othermail).get();
  const othertoken = da.data().token;
  console.log(`másik token: ${othertoken}`);

  resolve(othertoken);
});
```

Comment: I tried replacing my code with yours, also added async to the function, but I just get lots of errors. "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not a promise" and "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Can you share full file of it

Comment: Yes, here is the file: https://github.com/SlimLamie/firebaseshowit

Comment: I just given you the solution of promise, how can you create asynchronous with firebase, just replace the code I given with your code and debug where you got an error

Answer (score 0):

The reason why nothing gets returned is because the calls you are making to firestore are asynchronous. That is, when the execution actually reaches the if statement, the calls that you have made are not finished yet, and therefore `othertoken` has not received a value. As I see it, you can either make your method method asynchronous by marking it with the `async` keyword, and use `await`, or you can pass a callback to the function that accepts the token.
Using await:

```
const doc = await firestore.collection("mailpairing").doc(auth.currentUser.email).get();
const mail = doc.data().mail;
const token = await firestore.collection("tokens").doc(othermail).get();
const othertoken= da.data().token;

if(othertoken!=null){
    return (
        <>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => 
                    {window.location.href="tv/indexTv.html?m="+auth.currentUser.email+"&p="+othermail+"&t="+othertoken}} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </>
    )}
else {
    return null;
}
```

If using a callback, then you would declare a method that accepts the token as an argument:

```
const myCallback = token => {
    // do something with the token
}
```

and change your line `othertoken=da.data().token;` to `myCallback(da.data().token)` and pass `myCallback` to your function as argument.

Comment: I get this error when trying async/await: 
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: That is due to how you have defined the `render` prob in `Route`. According to the React Router documentation, the `render` attribute is used for "inline rendering". The attribute should be defined as a function that returns a React Element, but you have defined a function with no return value. What is your intention with defining it this way?

Comment: It seemed to be a working way. I want to redirect the site to another. Isn't it possible I get errors because of the async keyword?  Somewhere I read it components cannot be asyncronous.